# What is wrong Mvc.net 4.0.0.1 Razor 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

```
@{
string LoginIP = " ";
string LoginUser = " ";
```

}

```
<strong>    Aktiviteler | </strong><a href="#">user: <b>@LoginUser.ToString()&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b>@LoginIP.ToString()</b></a><br/>
```

It gives an "*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*" error``.

It's comic !

Comment: you should check url.

Comment: it's razor 2 markup problem. not html or url problem Iraj.

Comment: @TCCinoMarzano Are you sure it gives you an error on this particular line? Can you show the full code?

Comment: The code here is fine and does not throw an error. Your problem is elsewhere.